# apply iframe height dynamically

Tags: html, css, google-maps, iframe

I have a 2 column layout, first with a map (inside an iframe) and 2nd one with the info of the place.

Iframe witdh is working properly but I can't achieve to apply height dynamically to be same as 2nd column text.

Any ideas?

**MVCE**: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w5h49j1f/)

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2516.555272130855!2d4.339358315458401!3d50.894940979539264!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47c3c3ac00000001%3A0x5293071d68a63709!2sAtomium!5e0!3m2!1sca!2ses!4v1530871671353"
      width="95%" height="auto"></iframe>
    <!--  // tried with px or percentage -->
    </iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div> place information </div>
    <div> place information </div>
    <div> place information </div>
    <div> place information </div>
    <div> place information </div>
    <div> place information </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using flex properties.
https://jsfiddle.net/w5h49j1f/18/

```
.row { display: flex; }
.row > .column:first-child > div + div{ 
  height: calc(100% - 20px); /* for full height - subtracting the line-height of the title at the top in the 1st column  */
}
.row > .column iframe{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: not exactly what I need... it makes columns fixed height not dinamically.,,

Comment: No, its not a fixed height, it takes the height of content which has more height, dynamically. In the same Fiddle, the you can remove or increase the content of the right side column to see the  height of the map column changing accordingly. 
https://jsfiddle.net/w5h49j1f/35/

Comment: maybe whdth? sorry for my english :D... but at least is what my test show.... check it out here https://jsfiddle.net/w5h49j1f/28/ maybe im missing something....

Comment: I had only added the properties needed - height and flex properties. Width was already 50% in the previous post of yours and that was correct so I dint change it. In the Fiddle you posted now above, its missing, I have added it again. This should work/. https://jsfiddle.net/w5h49j1f/39/

Comment: true, my fault, but I still have same problem than the other answer.... `@media` property stop workig..... :(

Comment: I think you want the left column to be 100% width in smaller resolution. But, in @ media, instead of giving width 100% to left-column, you had given for iframe-holder class, that is inside the left-column class, so it dint work. Also, for @ media query to work, we need to add <meta> tag for viewport at <head> in the html. Now, I have posted the full code with all these fixes. This should work. https://jsfiddle.net/w5h49j1f/41/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mixture of flex and absolute positioning:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;  /* this makes columns equal height */
}

.column {
  width: 50%;
}

.left-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;   /* this allows the iframe holder to fill the rest of the column */
}

.iframe-holder {
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;             /* for growing the div to fill rest of space */
  position: relative;
}

.iframe-holder iframe {
  position: absolute;       /* make iframe fill div */
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width:100%;                /* overwrite inline attributes */
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column left-column">
    <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c" style="text-align: left;"><strong><span class="_38my">ON SOM:</span></strong></div>
    <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c iframe-holder" style="text-align: left;">
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2516.555272130855!2d4.339358315458401!3d50.894940979539264!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47c3c3ac00000001%3A0x5293071d68a63709!2sAtomium!5e0!3m2!1sca!2ses!4v1530871671353"
        width="95%" height="auto" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c" style="text-align: left;">

      Addresss

    </div>
    <div class="_5aj7 _3-8j _20ud" style="text-align: left;">
      <div class="_4bl9">
        <div>
          <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c"><strong><span class="_38my">Contact</span></strong></div>
          <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c">
            98798798798798798798
            <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c"><strong><span class="_38my">Time:</span></strong></div>
            987987987987987987987987987
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="u_fetchstream_1_u" class="_5aj7 _3-8j">
      <div class="_4bl7" style="text-align: left;">
        <div class="_2iem">
          <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c"><strong><span class="_38my">more and more info:</span></strong></div>
          <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c"><strong><span class="_38my">more and more info:</span></strong></div>
          <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c"><strong><span class="_38my">more and more info:</span></strong></div>
          <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c"><strong><span class="_38my">more and more info:</span></strong></div>
          <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c"><strong><span class="_38my">more and more info:</span></strong></div>
          <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c"><strong><span class="_38my">more and more info:</span></strong></div>
          <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c"><strong><span class="_38my">more and more info:</span></strong></div>
          <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c"><strong><span class="_38my">more and more info:</span></strong></div>
          <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c"><strong><span class="_38my">more and more info:</span></strong></div>
          <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c"><strong><span class="_38my">more and more info:</span></strong></div>
          <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c"><strong><span class="_38my">more and more info:</span></strong></div>
          <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c"><strong><span class="_38my">more and more info:</span></strong></div>
          <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c"><strong><span class="_38my">more and more info:</span></strong></div>
          <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c"><strong><span class="_38my">more and more info:</span></strong></div>
          <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c"><strong><span class="_38my">more and more info:</span></strong></div>
          <div class="_4-u3 _5dwa _5dwb _3v6c"><strong><span class="_38my">more and more info:</span></strong></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: close to what I need, but it does not allow the `@media` anotation work.... check it out here https://jsfiddle.net/w5h49j1f/26/

Comment: Yeah that should really be a new question as nowhere have you mentioned media queries in your above question and this answers the question posted, but here you go, as I'm kind, you are not increasing the width of the correct thing: https://jsfiddle.net/bu2aw4e0/2/

Comment: actually you're right, but I didn't expect `@media` annotation was affecting to this, thats why I didn't post it (and many other things) in the MVCE, hard to say where is the limit while I'm not a css expert